# Getting errors while trying to build a skeleton Mule Cloud Connector..

Tags: maven, mule, connector

So I'm following the tutorials online to build a cloud connector but I can't even get the skeleton to be generated!
[tutorial 1](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Using+the+Archetype)
[tutorial 2](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/build-your-cloud-connector-in-5-easy-steps/)

I get the following error, using the create-cloud-connector.bat script given by the [Mule Cloud Connect Development Kit](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/How+to+Build+a+Cloud+Connector)

```
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.170s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jul 30 13:00:57 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.mule.tools:mule-cloud-connector-archetype:2.0.16) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

what are some things I could be doing wrong?

- I updated the Maven settings.xml file
- the first question is " Name of the cloud service the new connector uses
  [default: ] " can I enter anything there? (or does it have to be like an existing service? what if I'm building one that doesn't exist?)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the tutorial is pointing at rather old version of the archetype (2.0.16) that maven can't even find.

I recommend to replace the generation step with the following command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.mule.tools.devkit -DarchetypeArtifactId=mule-devkit-archetype-cloud-connector -DarchetypeVersion=3.3.0
```

You can find additional informations [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-devkit)